# Python callback passing default argument

Tags: python, lambda, callback

I've been reading for the past half hour on various ways of constructing callbacks in Python and I haven't successfully passed a default parameter to be included when it "bounces back".

The code below demonstrates that I would like the integer 5 to be included when the callback is issued through exiting the Tkinter GUI.

```
class Heatmap(Updater):
""" Displays the Heatmap provided the data streaming in. """
def __init__(self, data_queue, slider_callback, closed_callback):
    """
    Initialization function for the Osc heatmap.
    :param data_queue: Data streamed in from the buffer for visualization.
    :type data_queue: Queue
    :param closed_callback: When the figure is closed, callback should be used to remove the figure.
    :type closed_callback: Function
    :param slider_callback: Callback function to return the state of the slider to parent caller.
    :type slider_callback: Function
    """
    super(Heatmap, self).__init__()

    self.data_queue = data_queue
    self.closed_callback = closed_callback
    self.slider_callback = slider_callback

    self.window = Tk()
    #self.window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', closed_callback)
    atexit.register(self.closed_callback)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
q = Queue()
for i in xrange(100):
    q.put(i)
def close_cb(idx):
    print 'idx {} window has been closed'.format(idx)
def slider_cb(val):
    print 'slidy {}'.format(val)
closely = lambda x: close_cb(5)
hm = Heatmap(q, slider_cb, closely)
hm.run()

ERROR
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I see the error is pointing towards my atexit.register(self.closed_callback) as it might expect some argument be passed through? How would I go about satisfying this while not passing fault info, all the while maintaining the fact that I receive 5 on a successful exit call back.

I've also been playing with functools.partial.

Comment: Are you asking how to set a default for a parameter of a lambda function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `lambda` expression doesn't require any formal parameters.

```
hm = Heatmap(q, slider_cb, lambda: close_cb(5))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'll mark it after the time. Whats the difference between lambda x: ... and lambda: ?

Comment: One requires an argument, the other does not. The parameter list has the same format as that in a `def` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question that you have tried `partial` but did not show us how you attempted it. Here is an example of how `partial` can be used in your case:

```
from functools import partial
hm = Heatmap(q, slider_cb, partial(close_cb, 5))
```